# Python: Reading from two array of tuples at a time and placing them side-by-side on CSV file

Tags: python, csv

So I have two arrays of tuples that are arranged with Restaurant Name and an Int:

```
("Restaurant Name", 0)
```

One is called ArrayForInitialSpots, and the other is called ArrayForChosenSpots. What I want to do is to write the tuples from both rows in side-by-side order in a csv file like this:

```
"First Restaurant in ArrayForInitialSPots",0,"First Restaurant in ArrayForChosenSpots", 1

"Second Restaurant in ArrayForInitialSpots",0,"Second Restaurant in ArrayForChosenSpots",0
```

So far i've tried doing this:

```
with open('data.csv','w') as out:
        csv_out=csv.writer(out)
        csv_out.writerow(['Restaurant Name','Change'])
        for x, y in zip(arrayForInitialSpots, arrayForChosenSpots):
            csv_out.writerow(x + y)
            #csv_out.writerow(y)
```

But I get:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 3-6: ordinal not in range(128)
```

If I remove the `zip` function, I get `too many values to unpack`. Any suggestions guys? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Any extended ascii characters in the Restaurant names? [extended ascii](http://web.itu.edu.tr/~sgunduz/courses/mikroisl/ascii.html)

Comment: Yeah there are some names that come weird. There are some places that start with "Café" for example, and I haven't integrated UTF-8. Any way to get around this? I just want to prepare the CSV file.

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or 3?

Comment: Python 2.7.9 to be exact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things that you could use to handle extended ascii characters while writing to files:

1. Set default encoding to utf-8

   `import sys
   reload(sys).setdefaultencoding("utf-8")`
2. Use unicodecsv writer to write data to files
   `import unicodecsv`
   [unicodecsv](https://github.com/jdunck/python-unicodecsv)

Answer (score 0):

with [mhawke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21945/mhawke) help here is my solution

```py
with open('data.csv','w') as out:
   csv_out=csv.writer(out)
   csv_out.writerow(['Restaurant Name','Change'])
   for x, y in zip(arrayForInitialSpots, arrayForChosenSpots):
      list_ = [str(word).decode("utf8") for word in (x+y)]
      counter = 0
      while counter < len(list_):
         s=""
         for i in range(counter,counter+4):
            s+=list_[i].encode('utf-8')
            s+=","
         counter = counter + 4
      csv_out.writerow(s[:-1])
```

Comment: even with `str(word)`?

Comment: ... and then you would write a row for each element of the tuple `l` the nett effect being that each item would appear on a single line.

Comment: hmmmm, what about a counter `i` with `i = i+2` within a while loop that encode `l[i]+","+l[i+1]` in each iteration?

Comment: I don't know, why don't you try it and see if it works?

Comment: Problem 1: What if the incoming data is already unicode? (`str()` might fail) Problem 2: You are manually creating a string of comma separated fields, and then using the csv module to write it.  You'll end up with a csv file with 1 column for each character in the string.  I don't think that's correct!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not due to your use of `zip()` - that looks OK, but instead it is an encoding issue. Probably the restaurant names are unicode strings or in some encoding other than ASCII or UTF8? ISO-8859-1 perhaps?

The csv module does not handle unicode; other encodings might work, but it depends. The module does handle 8-bit values OK (except ASCII NUL), so you should be able to encode them as UTF8 like this:

```
ENCODING = 'iso-8859-1'    # assume strings are encoded in this encoding

def to_utf8(item, from_encoding):
    if isinstance(item, str):
        # byte strings are first decoded to unicode
        item = unicode(item, from_encoding)
    return unicode(item).encode('utf8')

with open('data.csv', 'w') as out:
    csv_out = csv.writer(out)
    csv_out.writerow(['Restaurant Name', 'Change'] * 2)
    for x, y in zip(arrayForInitialSpots, arrayForChosenSpots):
        csv_out.writerow([to_utf8(item, ENCODING) for item in x+y])
```

This works by converting each element of the tuple formed by `x+y` into a UTF-8 string. This includes byte strings in other encodings, as well as other objects such as integers that can be converted to a unicode string via `unicode()`. If your strings are unicode, just set ENCODING to None.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/):

```
import numpy as np
IniSpots=[("Restaurant Name0a", 0),("Restaurant Name1a", 1)]
ChoSpots=[("Restaurant Name0b", 0),("Restaurant Name1b", 0)]
c=np.hstack((IniSpots,ChoSpots))
np.savetxt("data.csv", c, fmt='%s',delimiter=",")
```